# Installing a feature in servicemix

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, jtidy

I am running Apache servicemix 4.5.2. I want to install a feature, i.e. a jar file.
The feature I wanted is [jtidy](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev).

The pom dependence is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jtidy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
    <version>4aug2000r7-dev</version>
</dependency>
```

and the repository is

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar

I know the command **features:install webconsole**, for example but jtidy is not in my **features:list**. I've also tried using the addurl command but it didn't work.
(**addurl mvn:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev**)
The Karaf documentation recommends to add a feature descriptor using the Features XML schema but unfortunately the link is broken.

Up to know what i did is to download the jtidy.jar and copied it to my deploy directory. It works, but I don't think that this is the correct way.

Do anybody knows how to install jtidy in servicemix correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's difference between installing a feature and installing a single JAR or OSGi bundle.

A feature is defined in an XML file.  A feature consists of a number of bundles, configs, ... that are installed together.  Have a look at http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/provisioning.html to learn more about features in Karaf.

In this case, you want to install a single JAR into the container.  You can use the command `osgi:install` to do this, followed by a URL pointing to the JAR (e.g. `mvn:jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev`).

However, in your case, there's one more complexity. `jtidy` is not an OSGi bundle by itself.  The easiest way to add the necessary OSGi metadata, would be to use the `wrap:` protocol to automatically add the OSGi metadata to the JAR.

So, to wrap things up - to install this `jtidy` dependency in Apache ServiceMix, you can use

```
osgi:install wrap:mvn:jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW, what about if I want to add a jar developed by myself which is local to my environment (myJar.jar)?

Comment: If you're using Maven for development, the usual solution would be to build the artifact and then use the same kind of URL for your artifacts (mvn:<group id>/<artifact id>/<version>).  However, the URL can be anything you want really, so you can also use http://... or file:// to point to the artifact.